# Problem about understanding Relative Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

The Earth rotates on it's axis in 24 hours. So, we see the Sun rotates around Earth in 24 hours and the phenomenon is absolutely correct according to the principle of relative velocity.
Sun is approximately 1.5×10^8 km away from Earth.

If the Sun rotates around Earth, the distance covered by Sun is (2π×1.5×10^8) km = 9.4×10^8 km and the time is 24 hours or 86400 s

So, the speed of Sun = (9.4×10^8/86400) km/s = 1.1×10^7 m/s

It is less than the speed of light. So there is no problem. But what happens to those stars which are very very far away from Earth?

In this case those stars which are at least 2.6×10^10 km away from Earth gains the same speed as light which is impossible. So what is happening here? What is causing this phenomenon? Or, there are other situations that affect this incident?

It is my earniest request to the community to help me to find the solution of this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a very good question. In classical physics and special relativity the answer is that these rotating frames are simply not valid frames. To get a satisfying answer you would have to resort to general relativity but this is a very hard subject and this will be probably be out of reach (for a long time). If you want a teaser you can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging

Comment: In GR, you *can* use a rotating coordinate system, if you want to, but it makes the arithmetic messier. In such a system, the radial light rays turn into spirals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For linear motion, the choice of an inertial reference frame is pretty much arbitrary.  This is not true for rotation.  From what we know about the size of the universe and motions of the distant stars, it is not reasonable to assume that the universe is rotating about us.  It follows that a line of view from here to a very distant star can be taken as a line of reference for measuring a rotation. Still, the question of whether we go around the sun or it goes around us is not easiy answered (as evidenced by the length of time it took to arrive at our current opinion).  As I recall, it boils down to the fact that the heliocentric model gives a simpler explanation of the observed motion of the planets in the sky (and it is also consistent with Newton's laws).

Answer (score 0):

there is no privlaged inertial refrence frame. the spinning frame of the earth is non inertial and therfore isnt just as valid a refrence frame to decide if the earth is spinning or if the sun is spinning around the earth.